# How to display the Picker dropdown programmatically?

Tags: maui

How do you get the `Picker` dropdown window to show in Maui?

In Xamarin, you'd call `myPicker.Focus()`.  In Maui, this *almost* works, except that (unlike Xamarin) this does *not* cause the dropdown to be shown if the picker is already in focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension method works:

```
public static void DisplayPickerDropdown(this Picker picker)
{
    if(picker.IsFocused)
        picker.Unfocus();
    picker.Focus();
}
```

Then you can call `myPicker.DisplayPickerDropdown()`